# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when creating NSPredicate with NSDates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate, exc-bad-access

I am creating an NSPredicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
```

This solution has hundreds of upvotes here on StackOverflow, but for some reason its not working for me.

After the following line is executed, I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
RLMArray *finalCounts = [counts objectsWithPredicate:predicate];
```

I have made sure that both startDate and endDate log as NSDates, and I can't seem to find any other answers where the problem is brought up or answered.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Show us exactly the line where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs. The predicate itself may be correct but depending on where and how you use it might have some problem.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means something is getting over released. Instruments can tell you what, and when. It would also be helpful to post the stack trace of the crash in your question.

Comment: In the RLMArray.h objectsWithPredicate method returns RLMResults object.  Is it correct to set it equal to RLMArray?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug that's specific to a new persistence library that I'm using.